# How to automate analyzing log files?

Tags: logging, automation

I am aware of log analyzer. But instead of selecting files manually one by one and analyzing  has any one automated analyzing all the files for errors, if so how ?

Answer (score 2):

You can point the [Sitecore log analyzer](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Log_Analyzer.aspx) at a folder and it will analyze all the log files it finds. You can further filter by date when loading files from a folder.